# Accessing a method from another class

Tags: python, class

Below is my code

```
class MenuItem:

    def __init__(self, name, wholesale_cost, selling_price):
        self._name = name
        self._wholesale_cost = wholesale_cost
        self._selling_price = selling_price

    def get_menuitem_name(self):
        return self._name

class LemonadeStand:

    def __init__(self, stand_name):
        self._stand_name = stand_name
        self._current_day = 0
        self._menu_dict = {}
        self._sales_list_objects = []

    def get_name(self):
        return self._stand_name

    def add_menu_item(self, menu_item):
        # takes as a parameter a MenuItem object and adds it to
        # the menu dictionary.

        x = MenuItem.get_menuitem_name()
        self._menu_dict[x] = menu_item

        self._menu_dict[menu_item.get_menuitem_name()] = menu_item
```

My question is, how is it possible to have the code below?

```
self._menu_dict[menu_item.get_menuitem_name()] = menu_item
```

To me, the below code makes more sense because `get_menuitem_name()` is in the `MenuItem` class. Therefore, `MenuItem.get_menuitem_name()` makes sense.

```
x = MenuItem.get_menuitem_name()
self._menu_dict[x] = menu_item
```

But in the `self._menu_dict[menu_item.get_menuitem_name()] = menu_item`, `menu_item` is a parameter of the `add_menu_item()` method in the `LemonadeStand` class.

So, I'm curious to know how it is possible to call the `get_menuitem_name()` method from the `MenuItem` class in the `LemonadeStand` class with just a parameter from the `LemonadeStand` class.

Comment: Think about `MenuItem.get_menuitem_name()`. What is being passed in as the `self` argument? Nothing, so it'll fail. But if you call `menu_item.get_menuitem_name()` (where `menu_item` is an instance of `MenuItem`), the instance will be implicitly passed in as `self`, so it'll succeed. So I agree with ndc85430, you need to learn more about how classes work.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: BTW, [avoid getters and setters in Python. Use `property`s instead, or the bare attributes if possible.](/q/2627002/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the comments in the `add_menu_item` method - it takes "as a parameter a MenuItem object", that is an *instance* of the `MenuItem` class. From your question, it sounds like you need to do some learning about classes and how they're used. See, for example, the Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.